# grep or sed do not recognise GPS corrdinate string with degree

Tags: string, sed, grep, gps

the string looks like
(37°35'11.2" N 85°30'40.3"W)

grep does not work

```
grep -a "(37\°35\'11\.2\" N 85\°30\'40\.3\"W)" file.txt

grep  "(37\°35\'11\.2\" N 85\°30\'40\.3\"W)" file.txt

grep  -a "(37°35'11.2\" N 85°30'40.3\"W)" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One more generic way (you can change `\d` by numbers):

```
$ grep -P '\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+" N \d+.\d+.\d+.\d+..' l
37°35'11.2" N 85°30'40.3"W
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a shell quoting problem rather than a `grep` or `sed`. Do **not** escape the `°` and `'` characters enclosed in double-quotes with backslashes since they are not special between double-quotes (When those characters are "escaped" with backslashes, these backslashes are passed literally to the command, that is, they are not removed). Call the `grep` like this:

```
grep "(37°35'11.2\" N 85°30'40.3\"W)" file.txt
```

In shell, the characters that need to be escaped by a backslash when enclosed in double-quotes are `"`, `$`, `` ` ``, and the `\` itself. Also, the use of `-F` option of `grep` could be a good idea for this case because the regex argument of `grep` is treated as a fixed string.